# Python pool.apply_async() doesn't call target function?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, ubuntu-16.04

I'm writing an optimization routine to brute force search a solution space for optimal hyper parameters; and `apply_async` does not appear to be doing anything at all. Ubuntu Server 16.04, Python 3.5, PyCharm CE 2018. Also, I'm doing this on an Azure virtual machine. My code looks like this:

```
class optimizer(object):

    def __init__(self,n_proc,frame):

        # Set Class Variables

    def prep(self):

        # Get Data and prepare for optimization


    def ret_func(self,retval):

        self.results = self.results.append(retval)
        print('Something')

    def search(self):

        p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=self.n_proc)

        for x, y in zip(repeat(self.data),self.grid):

            job = p.apply_async(self.bot.backtest,(x,y),callback=self.ret_func)

        p.close()
        p.join()

        self.results.to_csv('OptimizationResults.csv')

        print('***************************')
        print('Exiting, Optimization Complete')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    opt = optimizer(n_proc=4,frame='ytd')
    opt.prep()
    print('Data Prepped, beginning search')
    opt.search()
```

I was running this exact setup on a Windows Server VM, and I switched over due to issues with `multiprocessing` not utilizing all cores. Today, I configured my machine and was able to run the optimization one time only. After that, it mysteriously stopped working with no change from me. Also, I should mention that it spits out output every 1 in 10 times I run it. Very odd behavior. I expect to see:

```
Something
Something
Something
 .....
```

Which would typically be the best "to-date" results of the optimization (omitted for clarity). Instead I get:

```
Data Prepped, beginning search
***************************
Exiting, Optimization Complete
```

If I call `get()` on the `async` object, the results are printed as expected, but only one core is utilized because the results are being gathered in the `for` loop. Why isn't `apply_async` doing anything at all? I should mention that I use the "stop" button on Pycharm to terminate the process, not sure if this has something to do with it?

Let me know if you need more details about `prep()`, or `bot.backtest()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error! Basically I was converting a `dict()` to a `list()` and passing the values from the list into my function! The list parameter order was different every time I ran the function, and one of the parameters needed to be an integer, not a float.

For some reason, on windows, the order of the dict was preserved when converting to a list; not the case with Ubuntu! Very interesting.